# Можно ли загружать данные в ObjectManager yandex maps асинхронно?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Можно ли загружать данные в ObjectManager yandex maps асинхронно?

1. Создаем карту
2. Создаем ObjectManager  в режиме кластера
3. Добавляем ObjectManager в карту.
4. Грузим данные
5. Добавляем данные в ObjectManager ( по его ссылке this.objectManager....)
6. Данные показываются на карте

У меня так почему-то не получается.

Comment: Приведите пример, как вы написали, чтобы понять, почему у вас не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в ангуляре, в ngIf.
Когда ngIf = false , div с картой не показывался и я добавлял в него точки.
Затем показывал div, ngIf = true.
Ошибок не было, но точки не появлялись.